# Attribute BOLD doesn't seem to work in my curses

Tags: python, linux, curses, bold

I use something like this: 
screen.addstr(text, color_pair(1) | A_BOLD), but it doesn't seem to work..
However, A_REVERSE and all others attribute does work!

In fact, I'm trying to print something in white, but the COLOR_WHITE prints it gray.. and after a while of searching, it seems that printing it gray + BOLD makes it!

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example code (Python 2.6, Linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import cycle
import curses, contextlib, time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def curses_screen():
    """Contextmanager's version of curses.wrapper()."""
    try:
        stdscr=curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        stdscr.keypad(1)
        try: curses.start_color()
        except: pass

        yield stdscr
    finally:
        stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()

if __name__=="__main__":
    with curses_screen() as stdscr:
        c = curses.A_BOLD
        if curses.has_colors():
            curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
            c |= curses.color_pair(1)

        curses.curs_set(0) # make cursor invisible

        y, x = stdscr.getmaxyx()
        for col in cycle((c, curses.A_BOLD)):
            stdscr.erase()
            stdscr.addstr(y//2, x//2, 'abc', col)
            stdscr.refresh()
            time.sleep(1)
```

All seems to be working.

Answer (score 5):

I tried this: `screen.addstr(text, curses.color_pair(1) | curses.A_BOLD)` and it worked!

So just add `curses.` and it should do the trick.
Of course at the beginning use: `import curses`