# Reading files by line location

Tags: python, function, parsing

So, I have a data file which has 3 columns. What I am trying to do is create a function that takes in start and end line number as input. Something like:

```
def(start line number, end line number):
    with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            splitted_line = line.strip().split(",")
            date1 = datetime.strptime(splitted_line[0],'%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S.%f')
            price = float(splitted_line[1])
            volume = int(splitted_line[2])
            my_tuple=(date1,price,volume)
```

Comment: @J Doe you should accept an answer if one worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(start,end):
    with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
        for idx,line in enumerate(f):
          if idx == end:
            break 
          if idx < start:
            continue

          splitted_line = line.strip().split(",")
          date1 = datetime.strptime(splitted_line[0],'%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S.%f')
          price = float(splitted_line[1])
          volume = int(splitted_line[2])
          my_tuple=(date1,price,volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, this function should only read the rows which are numbered in the range `[start_line, end_line]` (I'm assuming this is an inclusive range, i.e. you want to read both the start and end lines as well). Why not [write your for loop with enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/6157047) and simply skip rows that are out of the passed range?

```py
def read_line_range_inclusive(start_line, end_line):
    filename = "data.txt"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i < start_line: # will read the start line itself
                continue # keep going...
            if i > end_line: # will read the end line itself
                break # we're done

            # ... perform operations on lines ...
```

Also, be careful when splitting by commas; this works fine for simple rows like `1,2,3` but what about `1,2,"a,b,c",3`, where `"abc"` shouldn't be split into separate columns? I recommend using the [built-in csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which handles these edge cases automatically:

```
import csv

def read_line_range_inclusive(start_line, end_line):
    filename = "data.txt"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
            # row will already be separated into list
            # ... proceed as before ...
```

Note that you can only use the `with` statement on the file object itself, [not on the csv.reader parsed file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441446/6157047), so this wouldn't work: `with csv.reader(open(filename)) as f:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSV reader, you can access the line number:

```
csvreader.line_num
```

> The number of lines read from the source iterator. This is not the
>   same as the number of records returned, as records can span multiple
>   lines.

Answer (score 0):

We can combine the `linecache` module and `csv` to get the job done:

```
import csv
import linecache


def get_lines(filename, start_line_number, end_line_number):
    """
    Given a file name, start line and end line numbers,
    return those lines in the file
    """
    for line_number in range(start_line_number, end_line_number + 1):
        yield linecache.getline(filename, line_number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get lines 4-6 inclusive from the file
    lines = get_lines('data.txt', 4, 6)
    reader = csv.reader(lines)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Consider the data file, data.txt:

```
# this is line 1
# line 2

501,john
502,karen
503,alice

# skip this line
# and this, too
```

The above code will produce the following output:

```
['501', 'john']
['502', 'karen']
['503', 'alice']
```

## Discussion

- `linecache` is a lesser-known library which allow the user to quickly retrieve lines from a text file
- `csv` is a library to deal with comma-separated values
- By combining them, we can get the job done with little effort