# Terminal messed up (not displaying new lines) after running Python script

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, tty, stty

I have a Python script I use to execute commands in parallel across multiple hosts using the Python subprocess module.  It wraps SSH, and basically makes a call like this:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/env", env, "/usr/bin/ssh", "-t", "%s@%s" % (user, host), "--", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

The effective command gets executed like this:

```
/bin/env TERM=$TERM:password /usr/bin/ssh -t "%s@%s" % (user, host), "--", command
```

It works fine, except I get an intermittent error where my terminal gets messed up (loses newlines) after running the script.  A "reset" from the command line fixes it, but I'm not sure how this is happening, exactly.  I noticed that sometimes there's a **"\r\n"** at the end of the the first item in the tuple's output, and sometimes it's not there.  See the following, specifically "**Permission denied\r\n"**:

```
**** Okay output ****
[user@/home/user]# ./command.py hosts.lists "grep root /etc/shadow"
Running command "grep root /etc/shadow" on hosts in file "hosts.test"
('grep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied\r\n', 'Connection to server1.example.com closed.\r\n')
('grep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied\r\n', 'Connection to server2.example.com closed.\r\n')
[user@/home/user]#


**** Output causes terminal to not display newlines ****
[user@/home/user]# ./command.py hosts.list "grep root /etc/shadow"
('grep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied\r\n', 'Connection to server1.example.com closed.\r\n')
('grep: /etc/shadow: Permission denied\n', 'Connection to server2.example.com closed.\r\n')
                                 [user@/home/user]# [user@/home/user]# [user@/home/user]
```

The second output has been slightly modified, but shows the missing **"\r"**, and how my prompt gets "wacked" after running the script.

I think this is related to using the "-t" option in my subprocess command.  Somehow I'm losing the \r.  If I remove the "-t" option, this issue goes away, but long story short, I need it for passing through environmental variables for use on the remote machine (I'm hackishly using the TERM variable to pass through the user's password for sudo purposes, because I can't assume AcceptEnv is allowing arbitrary variable passing on the remote sshd server; I'm doing this to avoid passing the password on the command line, which will show up in the process list on the remote machine).

Just wondering if anyone knows a way to get around this, without removing the "-t" option?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like my tty settings get altered after running the **subprocess.Popen(...).communicate()** command within my script, regardless of whether or not I actually print the output to screen.  I find that really strange.  Here are the before/after differences in my tty config (from stty -a):

```
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff


opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0

isig icanon -iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
```

I'm wondering how to stop communicate() from altering my terminal settings?  Is it possible, or is this a bug?

Comment: does the *command* actually needs `-t` ssh option?

Comment: `.communicate()` doesn't alter your tty settings. Try some curses Python script that doesn't restore its settings on exit as a *command* and see whether you can reproduce the error reliably i.e., make the script accept a flag on whether to restore tty on exit or not.

Comment: for example, you could do nothing in the `finally` block if a `--no-restore` flag is passed in [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/327072/4279)

Comment: Yes, the command needs the "-t" option in order to pass through the local TERM variable, for something admittedly hackish I'm trying to do.  If I capture and restore the tty settings before and after .communicate(), I can fix the shell following completion of the command.  However, the output from my script gets very jumbled from all the extra spaces.  In situations where I run this script against large numbers of machines (not just two), it becomes unreadable.  I'm curious as to what's causing the extra output to my screen.

Comment: Have you tried to run the curses script?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try that.

Comment: Calling `.terminate()` on `output` will fix the terminal after the script ended. So `.terminate()` is restoring it to the initial setting, but this is not a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I found that

```
stty sane
```

restores the console to how it was before.
I didn't really understand the other answer here so I this helps someone.

Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/983755/os-x-terminal-behaves-oddly-after-running-python-interactively).

Comment: At least it helps after the terminal got messed up.

Comment: You can also try `reset` to get a similar result.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in a Perl script. To solve the problem I had to save the current settings of the local terminal (in order to restore it at the end of the script) and prepending "stty -raw" before executing the remote command.

So in Perl:

> #Save current terminal settings (you may add the PID in the filename)
>
> `stty -g > ~/tmp/.currentTtySettings`;
>
> #Execute remote command prepending "stty -raw"
>
> my @out=`ssh -t -q user@server1.example.com "stty -raw ; grep root /etc/shadow"`;
>
> #Restore terminal settings
>
> `stty \`cat ~/tmp/.currentTtySettings\``;

Hope it helps you!

Other very useful links:

-Detailed explanation of ssh and tty (-t option) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151916/why-is-this-binary-file-being-changed

-Some Perl and ssh inspiration http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod

-How to avoid "-t" for sudo https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password